# Docker Swarm, image can start, but how to interpret error code

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have several docker containers on Ubuntu, but when I deploy them I have no log.
But with this command I have an error code, see:

```
ID                          NAME                                    IMAGE
                                                                          NODE                          DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE           ERROR                       PORTS
7sutdpifo8dfgszhpupg1cocr   identity_identityserver.1       registry.gitlab.com/myreg/mycorp/identityserver:1.0.684@sha256:3013e4fca0a2114d523e82ca09fcc31e772614e0633d80b45dc8a1424cfb7e55   vmi366339.myhosting.net   Running             Running 6 seconds ago
aca6n64b4v2s1gx3udo3x7z4x    \_ identity_identityserver.1   registry.gitlab.com/myreg/mycorp/identityserver:1.0.684@sha256:3013e4fca0a2114d523e82ca09fcc31e772614e0633d80b45dc8a1424cfb7e55   vmi366339.myhosting.net   Shutdown            Failed 13 seconds ago   "task: non-zero exit (1)"
0732wp72lq26vrs7lzqz6devx    \_ identity_identityserver.1   registry.gitlab.com/myreg/mycorp/identityserver:1.0.684@sha256:3013e4fca0a2114d523e82ca09fcc31e772614e0633d80b45dc8a1424cfb7e55   vmi366339.myhosting.net   Shutdown            Failed 25 seconds ago   "task: non-zero exit (1)"
pvk32f71d36qxmxnjmmyghkl6    \_ identity_identityserver.1   registry.gitlab.com/myreg/mycorp/identityserver:1.0.684@sha256:3013e4fca0a2114d523e82ca09fcc31e772614e0633d80b45dc8a1424cfb7e55   vmi366339.myhosting.net   Shutdown            Failed 39 seconds ago   "task: non-zero exit (1)"
k71kbeu6x6ob0n4l94chzovg3    \_ identity_identityserver.1   registry.gitlab.com/myreg/mycorp/identityserver:1.0.684@sha256:3013e4fca0a2114d523e82ca09fcc31e772614e0633d80b45dc8a1424cfb7e55   vmi366339.myhosting.net   Shutdown            Failed 52 seconds ago   "task: non-zero exit (1)"
```

I only have this message: "task: non-zero exit (1)"

Also, my docker logs are empty and the application are empty too.

I got this error since our migration to .NET 5, we build our images with the following docker file:

```
### >>> GLOBALS
ARG ENVIRONMENT="Production"
ARG PROJECT="IdentityServer.Host"
### <<<

#--------------------------------------------------
# Build / Publish
#--------------------------------------------------

# debian buster - AMD64
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

### >>> IMPORTS
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PROJECT
### <<<

ARG NUGET_CACHE=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
ARG NUGET_FEED=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

# Copy sources
COPY src/ /app/src
ADD common.props /app

WORKDIR /app

# Installs NodeJS to build typescripts
#RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
#RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential
#RUN npm install -g npm
#RUN npm install

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g parcel-bundler

# Installs the required dependencies on top of the base image
# Publish a self-contained image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev && dotnet dev-certs https; \
    dotnet dev-certs https --clean;  \
    dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime linux-x64 -c Debug -o out src/${PROJECT};

#--------------------------------------------------
# Execute
#--------------------------------------------------

# Start a new image from aspnet runtime image
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS runtime

### >>> IMPORTS
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PROJECT
### <<<

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:80;https://+:443;https://+:44385" 
#ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:80"  
ENV PROJECT="${PROJECT}.dll"

# Make logs a volume for persistence
VOLUME /app/Logs

# App directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy our build from the previous stage in /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./

# Installs the required dependencies on top of the base image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg libgdiplus libc6-dev

# Ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 44385

# Execute
ENTRYPOINT dotnet ${PROJECT}
```

I have change this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
to this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

Is there another way to check why an app does not start?

Comment: have you tried to check  task` logs? `docker service logs #task#` will return logs for specific service task

Comment: Also, maybe you forgot to change the runtime version to 5.0 from 3.1?